# Make two objects grow at same rate?

Tags: processing

I have this program wrritten up, it works ok but the stem and flower grow at different rates. How can i make the two grow at the same rate? I have been struggling with this for a day or two now and I know it may seem simple, but its been a pain to me :P

Comment: It's hard to answer this question right now. There's too much code, it's not easy to run to see the issue and the problem description is a little vague. Can you give us a more concise snippet of the problem? Maybe remove the items that don't affect the outcome? You might even find the problem yourself when doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you cannot easily sync the two animations is because the stems are growing based on the frameCount and the flower was growing based on a ratio that was not based on the frameCount or frameRate. I have modified your Flower class, very quickly to illustrate where the issue is:

before anything is called in `Flower.display()` method:

```
scale(-min((float)(frameCount)/250, 1), min((float)(frameCount)/250, 1));
```

This is similar to how you are scaling the stems.

in the `Flower.grow()` method:

```
factor = maxFactor;
sizes = maxSize;
```

This is sloppy but quick. Just forces the flower to draw at its largest size, while the modification above scales it.

Here is the full source, with comments and commented out code:

```
Stem myStem;
 Circle circles[];
 Flower flowers = new Flower();
 float scaleFactor=0.5;

 void setup() {
   size(floor(400*scaleFactor), floor(800*scaleFactor));
   myStem = new Stem(200, 800);
   flowers = new Flower (0, 0);
   //moved this to setup, no need to recreate each frame
   circles = new Circle[6];
   circles[0]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
   circles[1]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
   circles[2]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
   circles[3]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
   circles[4]  = new Circle(0, -40, 50, 50);
   circles[5]  = new Circle(0, 0, 50, 50);
   // also smooth only needs to be called once
   // unless ther is a noSmooth() somewhere
   smooth();
   }

   void draw() {

   float grow = 0;
   //translate(myStem.initalloX, myStem.initalloY);  
   myStem.drawStem();
   //set centre point
   translate(myStem.initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?myStem.initalloY-       500:myStem.initalloY-(2*frameCount)));
   if (frameCount>10) {
     flowers.grow();
     flowers.display();
     }
   } 

   class Stem { 
     int initalloX=200;
     int initalloY=800;

     Stem(int tempInitalloX, int tempInitalloY) {
      initalloX = tempInitalloX;
      initalloY = tempInitalloY;
     }

 void drawStem() {
   background(#0DBADB);
   scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
   stroke (12, 149, 11);
   fill (12, 149, 11);
   strokeWeight(10);
   line(initalloX, initalloY, initalloX, ((frameCount>250)?initalloY-500:initalloY-(2*frameCount)));
   //stem1
   if (frameCount>101) {
      noStroke();
      translate(initalloX, initalloY-200);
      scale(min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
      beginShape();
      vertex(0, 0);
      bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
      bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
      endShape(CLOSE);
      scale(1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-100)/100, 1));
      translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-200));
      noStroke();
    }
    //stem2
    if (frameCount>151) {
     //  noStroke();
     translate(initalloX, initalloY-300);
     scale(-min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
     beginShape();
     vertex(0, 0);
     bezierVertex(-40, -5, -30, -40, -80, -20);
     bezierVertex(-47, -16, -52, 8, 0, 0);
     endShape(CLOSE);
     scale(-1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1), 1/min((float)(frameCount-150)/150, 1));
     translate(-initalloX, -(initalloY-300));
     }
   }
 }

 class Circle {

   int c1 = 0;
   int c2 = -40;
   float c3 = 50;
   float c4 = 50;

   Circle(int tc1, int tc2, float tc3, float tc4) {
   c1 = tc1;
   c2 = tc2;
   c3 = tc3;
   c4 = tc4;
   }
  }

 class Flower {

 float centerX;
 float centerY;
 float posX;
 float posY;
 float maxSize = 51;
 float maxFactor = 40;
 float sizes = 0;
 float factor = 0;
 float speed = 0.17;

 Flower() {
 }
 Flower(float _centerX, float _centerY)
 {
  centerX = _centerX;
  centerY = _centerY;
 }
 void setCenter(float x, float y)
 {
  centerX = x;
  centerY = y;
 }
 void display()
 {
   // added line below
   scale(-min((float)(frameCount)/250, 1), min((float)(frameCount)/250, 1));
   for (int i = -18; i < 360; i+=72)
   {
      posX = centerX + cos(radians(i)) * factor;
      posY = centerY + sin(radians(i)) * factor;
     noStroke();
     fill(170, 14, 24); // blue
     ellipse(posX, posY, sizes, sizes);
   }
   fill(14, 17, 170);
   ellipse(centerX, centerY, sizes , sizes );
 }
 void grow()
 {
//   factor = (factor < maxFactor )?  factor + speed: maxFactor;
//   sizes = (sizes < maxSize )?  sizes + speed*1.3 : maxSize;
   // modified line below
   factor = maxFactor;
   sizes = maxSize;
 }
}// end of Flower
```